# Android Export - Duplicate Entry: CVS/Entries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, cvs

I am trying to export my Android project for final review and then for publishing. When trying to export it as a signed application, it gives me a generic "Failed to export application" error. If I try exporting as an unsigned application, it atleast gives me a bit more detail: "Failed to export application - duplicate entry: CVS/Entries".

My project uses CVS for version control, and does have the typical "CVS" folder in each sub-folder. I've tried adding "CVS" as an exclusion from the build path under Java Build Path. I've also tried adding a filter of "**/CVS*". Eclipse does effectively ignore the CVS folders it appears, as they have never shown up in my Project Explorer.

I've tried multiple Clean Projects, disabling automatic building, and running a manual build. I've also made sure that Eclipse, ADT, and Android SDK Manager stuff are all updated. I'm at a loss on what is going on, and how to effectively fix it.

So far, I've only found results on using Ant, which I do not use since I am using the tools through Eclipse. I've been able to build the debugging versions with no such issues for months.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I ended up copying all of the files into a different project without CVS (and named it with a suffix "- Builder"), and it exported as signed with no problem. This is a bit of an inconvenience, as this means I have to manually copy any revised files over to this project anytime I want to build a release.